# matplotlib savefig bbox_inches = 'tight' does not ignore invisible axes

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

When you set bbox_inches = 'tight' in Matplotlib's savefig() function, it tries to find the tightest bounding box that encapsulates all the content in your figure window.  Unfortunately, the tightest bounding box appears to include invisible axes.

For example, here is a snippet where setting bbox_inches = 'tight' works as desired:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
data_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
data_ax.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.savefig('Test1.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

which produces:

[image: Nice tight bounding box]

The bounds of the saved pdf correspond to the bounds of the content.  This is great, except that I like to use a set of invisible figure axes to place annotations in.  If the invisible axes extend beyond the bounds of the visible content, then the pdf bounds are larger than the visible content.  For example:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
fig_ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frame_on = False)
fig_ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
fig_ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
data_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])
data_ax.plot([1,2], [1,2])
plt.savefig('Test2.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

producing

[image: Loose bounding box]

How can I force savefig() to ignore invisible items in the figure window?  The only solution I have come up with is to calculate the bounding box myself and explicitly specify the bbox to savefig().

In case it matters, I am running Matplotlib 1.2.1 under Python 2.7.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: I would point out the axes is sill visible, you just made the axis objects not visible.  add `fig_ax.patch.set_color('r')` before you save the figure to see this.

Comment: and why do you put the annotations on a separate axes?

Comment: @tcaswell I just tried inserting `fig_ax.patch.set_color('r')` right after `fig_ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)` and the pdf looks the same.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.  I put my annotations on a separate set of axes so that the annotations can extend beyond the data axes and so I can specify the position in millimeter units instead of data units.  Perhaps there is a way to meet these requirements without having a separate set of axes...

Comment: yes, `annotate` will take location in all manner of units.  http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate

Comment: ah, the patch didn't show up because `frameon=False` hides it (sorry, my bad), but my point still stands.  The `fig_ax.get_visble() == True` and `fig_ax.get_window_extent()` will set your bounding box

Comment: @tcaswell Yeah, I understand that `fig_ax.get_window_extent()` is setting my bounding box.  I just think the bounding box should be set by what is visible, not what is invisible.

Comment: @tcaswell I used the term annotations loosely.  I looked at `annotate` and it pertains to leader lines to label specific curves and features inside the data axes.  I create my own custom x-axis and y-axis labels and place them in the `fig_ax`.  I'll look into other methods to place them.

Comment: It _is_ set by what is visible in _as far as the code is concerned_ the axes you have in the back is visible -> it gets factored in.  There is no other sensible way to do it.  As for creating your own axes ticks there is an entire set of tools for locating and formatting ticks.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html  http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39101/discussion-between-tcaswell-and-stretch)

Answer (score 3):

The relevant function (called by `canvas.print_figure` which is called by `figure.savefig` to generate the bounding box) in `backend_bases.py`:

```
def get_tightbbox(self, renderer):
    """
    Return a (tight) bounding box of the figure in inches.

    It only accounts axes title, axis labels, and axis
    ticklabels. Needs improvement.
    """

    bb = []
    for ax in self.axes:
        if ax.get_visible():
            bb.append(ax.get_tightbbox(renderer))

    _bbox = Bbox.union([b for b in bb if b.width != 0 or b.height != 0])

    bbox_inches = TransformedBbox(_bbox,
                                  Affine2D().scale(1. / self.dpi))

    return bbox_inches
```

The only consideration that goes into deciding if an axes is 'visible' is if `ax.get_visible()` returns true, even if you have no visible (either `artist.get_visible() == False` or simple transparent) artists in the axes.

The bounding box behavior you observe is the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

tcaswell, thanks for your help.  My original question was, "How can I force savefig() to ignore invisible items in the figure window?"  When I put `fig_ax.set_visible(False)` then `savefig()` ignores the invisible axes.  Unfortunately, when I set `fig_ax.set_visible(False)` then any artist placed in fig_ax is also invisible.  I am back to the original plot I posted, where `fig_ax` does not exist.

As you intimated in your comment, tcaswell, I think the proper solution is avoid creating `fig_ax`.  I am currently working on placing my annotations and data axis labels in the default figure object `fig`.  It's a bit annoying since `fig` uses normalized figure units instead of mm units, but I can deal with it.

Comment: @tcaswell Good point. `annotate` works well for text, since you can can specify `textcoords='figure points'`.  I'm not sure how to do arbitrary patches though.  Perhaps `ConnectionPatch` will work...

Comment: Also see http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html you can (mostly) easily go from screen space (in pixels, which if you control dpi gives you inches) -> figure fraction with the inverse transformation to sort out where to put arbitrary patches.