# matplotlib: Get resulting bounding box of `bbox_inches=tight`

Tags: matplotlib

I often produce individual figures with matplotlib which are supposed to be aligned vertically or horizontally e.g. in a LaTeX document. My goals are:

1. Avoid excessive margins or clipping in all figures. For stand-alone figures this is easily solved by using `bbox_inches='tight'` in `savefig`.
2. Use the exact same bounding box for all figures, since I want my axes elements to line up nicely in the resulting document.

My current solution is a very inconvenient trial and error approach: I manually try to guess reasonable margins and set them via [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust). This often takes a lot of time until I have a satisfactory result.

I'm wondering if it is possible to combine the power of `bbox_inches='tight'` with `plt.subplots_adjust()`? Is it possible to programmatically get the resulting bounding box of `bbox_inches='tight'`? This would allow my to determining the bounding box for the figure with the largest axis labels/titles, and use this bounding box for all other figures.

Comment: Note that I also have to use the figures individually, so I cannot glue them together in matplotlib itself as subplots.

Comment: @tcaswell provided [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19335925/2043505) a while ago, it might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Schorsch and [@tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19335925/1804173) for pointing out that `ax.get_tightbbox` almost solves this problem. The only tricky part is to convert the renderer dependent bbox into an "inches" bbox. The general solution is:

```
tight_bbox_raw = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
tight_bbox = TransformedBbox(tight_bbox_raw, Affine2D().scale(1./fig.dpi))
```

I can now reuse the `tight_bbox` for my other plots as well, resulting in nice, identically boxed figures.

I have also written a small helper class -- not elegant, but useful: I call `max_box_tracker.add_figure` for every figure I create, and it will internally update a maximum bounding box. After generating all plots, I can print out the resulting bounding box (directly in the form of code to add to my script).

```
class MaxBoxTracker:
  def __init__(self):
    self.box = None
  def add_figure(self, fig, ax):
    from matplotlib.transforms import TransformedBbox, Affine2D
    box_raw = ax.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
    box = TransformedBbox(box_raw, Affine2D().scale(1./fig.dpi)).get_points()
    if self.box is None:
      self.box = box
    else:
      self.box[0][0] = min(self.box[0][0], box[0][0])
      self.box[0][1] = min(self.box[0][1], box[0][1])
      self.box[1][0] = max(self.box[1][0], box[1][0])
      self.box[1][1] = max(self.box[1][1], box[1][1])
  def print_max(self):
    print 'Code to set maximum bbox:\nfrom matplotlib.transforms import Bbox\ntight_bbox = Bbox([[%f, %f], [%f, %f]])' % (
      self.box[0][0], self.box[0][1], self.box[1][0], self.box[1][1]
    )
```

Comment: For anyone reading this thread: not sure if it is necessary to iterate through every axes; in Matplotlib 2.x, I can simply call **`bbox = fig.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())`** and the result is a bounding box surrounding **every Artist in the figure**, already transformed to units inches. Per the description: "It only accounts axes title, axis labels, and axis ticklabels" so be advised. But most of the time that is all I care about.