# Get rid of external white spaces from matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, image, matplotlib, plot

I want to get rid of white spaces from this plot. The plot is from `mne` library example [here](https://mne.tools/stable/auto_tutorials/time-freq/20_sensors_time_frequency.html#inspect-power). I only want to data in the box and nothing else. I converted the plot to image like this:

```
def get_img_from_fig(fig, dpi=180):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf, format="png", dpi=fig.dpi)
    buf.seek(0)
    img_arr = np.frombuffer(buf.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
    buf.close()
    img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, 1)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return img
```

[image]

I tried a lot of things including this:

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img_orig_2)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches = 0, dpi = 180)
plt.show()
```

but it won't get rid of the white space. What should I do, apart from manually cropping or setting the aspect ratio?

**EDIT:**
Added the code to plot without axes and the link to the code for reference.

Comment: How did you remove the axis and from the looks you were using cmap, so that color scale as well? Depending how that removing was done [matplotlib savefig bbox_inches = 'tight' does not ignore invisible axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328610/matplotlib-savefig-bbox-inches-tight-does-not-ignore-invisible-axes) may be of relevance for you.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ and self contained minimal example.  Otherwise its really hard to know why this isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have added the code and the link for reference.